# How reduce the height of an mschart by breaking up the y-axis

Tags: c#, graph, mschart

How can I reduce the height of an mschart like this:

[image: Chart with flat area]

[EDIT]
In my case I do not want break chart view.

```
this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: Explain better!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for `AxisY.ScaleBreakStyle`.

Here is an example:

[image]

```
Series s = chart1.Series[0];
ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
Axis ay = ca.AxisY;
s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) s.Points.AddXY(i, rnd.Next(100) + 50 );
s.Points.AddXY(s.Points.Count, 123456);

ay.ScaleBreakStyle.Enabled = true;   // <<<=== enable or disable!
ay.ScaleBreakStyle.LineWidth = 1;
ay.ScaleBreakStyle.LineColor = Color.OrangeRed;
ay.ScaleBreakStyle.StartFromZero = StartFromZero.Auto;
ay.ScaleBreakStyle.Spacing = 2;
ay.ScaleBreakStyle.StartFromZero = StartFromZero.Auto;
```

Note that there a quite a few cases where it will not work. [MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axisscalebreakstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Scale breaks are not supported under any of the following conditions:

- Pie, doughnut, funnel, pyramid, radial or any stacked chart types are used.
- Custom intervals for labels, tick marks or grid lines are enabled.
- The minimum or maximum value for the axis is set.
- Custom labels are used.
- A logarithmic Y-axis is specified.
- Axis views on the Y-axis, which include scrolling and zooming, are used.
- 3-D charts are used.

**Update:** Of course you can also **disable** the break at runtime..

Comment: Yes. I had one call for that, only for second graph. When I searched I located. +1