# C# - Visual Studio - How can I make chart update in real time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts, stock

basically im making a gui that shows a chart, and has a database.
the database table has 2 fields: Id, and Price
I'm trying to make the chart a line chart that updates and keeps the past 50 or so x values, but it keeps being a bar chart and it includes all the information, it wont truncate to only max 50 'x-values':

```
        // create database/tables
        StockDBDataSet_JEROTableAdapters.TableTableAdapter JERO_table = new StockDBDataSet_JEROTableAdapters.TableTableAdapter();

        // loop indefinitely changing prices per duration set
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            chrtJERO.Series.Clear();
            chrtJERO.DataBindTable(JERO_table.GetData(), "Id");
            JERO_table.Insert(i, JERO.Price);
            JERO.ChangePrice();
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
```

what am i doing wrong? btw I'm a beginner in C#, if that helps with context.
Thanks!

Comment: `chrtJERO.Series.Clear();` Don't clear all the series!. Set `Series[0].ChartType`to Line and let it be! - You could clear the Points in the Series before binding to a new set of data, if that is what your adapter will deliver.

Comment: @TaW I can just set the chart type property within the GUI of Visual Studio rightt?
 no need to do it incode? and How do I clear the points? if I delete the `chrtJERO.Series.Clear()` line, i get this error: `An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A chart element with the name 'Price' already exists in the 'SeriesCollection'.`

Comment: a) yes. goto Chart properties - Series (Diagram) - ChartType - b) someSeries.Points.Clear() will remove all DataPoints from that Series. c) the error means that you try to add the same series again. Simply don't do that. Usually there is no need to add Series after the initial setup.

Comment: @TaW - ok sorry, it's still giving me that error. I'm confused on what exactly to do; i never really got formal education on this so sorry if I keep bugging you xD but here's my code:
`for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            {
                chrtJERO.Series[0].Points.Clear();
                chrtJERO.DataBindTable(JERO_table.GetData(), "Id");
                JERO_table.Insert(i, JERO.Price);
                JERO.ChangePrice();
                await Task.Delay(100);
            }`

Comment: Don't clear inside the loop! Move it before the loop! Probably: Also move the DataBind command out of the loop! I don't know what  JERO.ChangePrice();  does?

Comment: @TaW oh, i thought i had to call the bind every time i add data to the chart after changing the price. Basically JERO is an object (Stock), and .changeprice() changes the price, and i insert it into the database in which im binding it to a chart. thus creating an actual chart; if that makes any sense. but yeah thanks!

Comment: yes, you may be right. So first move out the clear command!

Comment: @TaW yay! it's fixed now. now my problem is with "zooming" into the chart. basically it show the y axis from 0 to whatever price it is, i want it to "zoom" into the price, so that the axis is showing only like +-n, n being relative to whatever price the value is at. kinda like stock charts: https://www.google.com/search?q=tsla+stock

Comment: @TaW nvm found it, it's called ScaleBreakStyle. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Well, there are already many post here that show hot to implement zooning in on a chart. Note: You can only zoom into the data that are present! if you keep removing all but 100 points you can only zoom into those.

Comment: not sure if you are right. `ScaleBreakStyle` does what is says: It breaks the axis apart to make the far away points visible without including the whole value range. Best see an example eg [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43279241/how-reduce-the-height-of-an-mschart-by-breaking-up-the-y-axis/43280513?s=14|0.0000#43280513). - Also note that the tesl example doesn't really zoom in or out. It offers a choice of various data resolutions, ie the data are all different. Chart zooming instead lets you or the user zoom in or out in the same set of data..